# How can we render any type of data (ID,Image,Description,ImageId) from MySql using angular4 or angular4+?

Tags: angular

How can we render all type of data form mysql using angular4 or 4+?
[Component file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WHQf.png)
[`services`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4rKK.png)
[`Html file`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftKoy.png)

```
`export interface Iposts {
    id :number;
    name:string;
    icon:string;
    shortDesc:string;
    topic_id:string;

}`
```

Comment: Please Share your code.

Comment: please click on images for checking code snippet

Comment: What do you mean by render? Use string interpolation in the template file. {{}} For images use property binding with SRC attribute

Comment: fetching data form DB , and i already tried SRC attribute it giving null values,

Comment: what response your are getting from your API? share your response

Comment: It is solved by routing of database ...Thank you for your appreciation @Najamussaqib